# How to find cubic root without using any loop or conditional statement

Tags: operators, root

I am finding a way to find a cubic root without using any loop or conditional statement. I am currently learning C that learnt basic operator and bits. Professor told me that there is a way to find cubic root without using any loop and conditional statement. I used pow first but he told me not to use that. Saying that you can only use basic operator. Is there any way to do that. I already search in stack overflow for 2 hours but I haven't find a clue.

I tried to find a way using loop but don't know how to do it without thoes

Answer (score 0):

My guess:
`x^(1/3)=y  ==>  y=2^(log2(x)/3)`

To calculate `log2(x)` see: "Feynman's algorithm" in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm